# mixed string Hebrew and English and catch the first 10 chars complete to last word

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, pcre

I have a mixed string Hebrew and English and I want to catch the first 10 chars without cutting a word in the middle. for example:

```
    >שלום is peace not a war
```

I use:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05ff ]{1,10}\b/i
```

my result: `שלום is [0-7]`

without the b flag result is: `שלום is pe [0-9]`

required result is: `שלום is peace [0-12]`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\p{Hebrew}` property to match Hebrew characters.

```
$re = '/^[a-zA-Z\p{Hebrew} ]{10,}?\b/mu'; 
$str = "שלום is peace not a war"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF7vT6/1)

Comment: Nop.
This return an empty var in PHP.

Comment: You are absolutely right
I checked again and found my problem with the page encoding.
Thank you
Your answer helped me a lot and your insistence too.